# Python application doesn't open with Pygame (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame

I'm trying to build a snake game in my Mac using Python3 and Pygame, but when I run the game with `python3 snakegame.py`, the app called `Python` just keeps jumping up and down on the desktop (I assume loading to open), but it never does open. I'm not sure if I have to open it with `Python Launcher` or something else. Thank you! Here is my code if you need it:

```
import pygame

def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,0),(x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (0,y),(w,y))

def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    drawGrid(width,rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    global width, rows
    width = 500
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    #s = snake((255, 0, 0), (10, 10))
    flag = True;

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag == True:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        redrawWindow(win)
    pass

main()
```

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message? Code works correctly on LInux so problem can be your system.  On some system pygame can close if you don't get events.

Comment: I just ran it in my terminal in my MacOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,0),(x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (0,y),(w,y))

def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    drawGrid(width,rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    global width, rows
    width = 500
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    #s = snake((255, 0, 0), (10, 10))
    flag = True;

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag == True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                flag = False
                
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        redrawWindow(win)
    pass

main()
```

I have updated your program with the ability to quit, and when i tested it, the window went non responding, that is because you didn't check the events that are currently occuring. So i added a loop to check the events, and now your program stays responding.

Comment: Hey @RocknRollDelta! Thanks for the effort in answering my question! I tried doing what you told me, but the pygame window still doesn't open...

Comment: hmmm i think i know the problem you forgot to add pygame.init() after pygame.

Comment: Hey! But where should I put this?

Comment: after `import pygame`

Comment: I did this. It told me for the first time to for me to allow terminal to open applications, some preference. So I thought it finally worked, but it still just keeps loading forever.

Comment: this is a problem with your terminal, because it loads perfectly fine with me. and can you link a picture to what is occuring along with the ide u are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217405/discussion-between-nicolas-fuchs-and-rocknrolldelta).